# producing m-member combination in a n-member array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, combinations

I have an array with `n` members. And I have another number: `m`,(`m <= n`) which is entered by user. Now I want to produce all of possible "m" member combination in the array.

```
A[5] = {a,b,c,d,e};
B = 3
Number of combination: C(5, 3) = 10
```

Now I want a code for showing these 10 combination.like:

```
{{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{a,b,e},.....}
```

Order of items in permutation is important. For example `{a,b,d}` is right but `{b,d,a}` is wrong. The permutation items should come in their order in our matrix.

I appropriate any help from your side. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not permutations that you want but combinations (even if the solution I gave is with permutation of *mask*).

Comment: Yes, because order of members is important, so it is combination not permutation.tnx

Comment: @shirin that doesn't directly follow from your statement.  For combinations, order generally doesn't matter. What you want is an *ordered combination* (which is a subset of the permutations of a set)

Comment: @JoelCornett I think you might have misunderstood the question. OP gave `{b,d,a}` as an example of what *not* to output, because they want the normalized form `{a,b,d}`. My interpretation is that they want exactly the m-combinations of the set A

Comment: What have you done? Is there any code snippet to view?  Are you asking us to solve your homework?  Please, put this question on hold!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For combination:

```
template <typename T>
void Combination(const std::vector<T>& v, std::size_t count)
{
    assert(count <= v.size());
    std::vector<bool> bitset(v.size() - count, 0);
    bitset.resize(v.size(), 1);

    do {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
            if (bitset[i]) {
                std::cout << v[i] << " ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(bitset.begin(), bitset.end()));
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/86h2wn)

Comment: @NiklasB.: would be possible for a superset. In your suggestion, we have to count how many bit are set :/. (I may also add that if OP wants each pair of a vector of 129 element, your `int` is too short).

Comment: You're right, is missed that part :)